# Lose gnome3 wallpaper

Tags: debian, gnome3, desktop

My wallpaper is now white, the icons are displayed, but the app in parameters/background does not launch.

In gconf, /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename is set to a valid image (I can see my wallpaper when I'm under the Activity mode)

I'm using debian testing updated today.

Any clue? Need other Infos?

See the [image: screenshot]

Comment: What happens if you restart `nautilus`? `nautilus -q; nautilus&`?

Comment: nothing special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just solved it, in gnome tweak tool under Desktop tab I disabled option "Have file manager handle the desktop".

Comment: This worked but the app to change the background is still crashing and now I don't have my shortcuts on the desktop anymore.